# tinytex::tlmgr() could not initialize from ctan

Tags: r, proxy, httr, tinytex

I try to install the pdflscape package from ctan using the r package tinytex.

Running `tinytex::tlmgr_install("pdflscape.sty")` produces the following error:

`TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: http://ctan.mines-albi.fr//tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`

In my organization, I usually have to use a proxy, for example using `httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy())` but this did not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess you may try to change the repository with "tlmgr option repository $newlink$", since I am having the same issue and tlmgr suggests that (error message: /usr/local/bin/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed)